# Which components between wideband antenna and several SDRs working on different frequency ranges?

Tags: rf

I usually use narrow-band antenna fitted for one scenario, and connect it to a SDR. Here at the opposite, I need to connect a wideband antenna (Log-periodic 430 to 6000MHz) to several SDR (LimeSDR or USRP B310): one SDR working on 433MHz, two working on 2.4-2.5GHz and one working on 5.8-5.9GHz. On one installation the SDR are all the same, 50ohms (like the antenna) and are only receiving - they never transmit. I have already used splitters (Wilkinson and resistive ones) and diplexers, but here I am lost on which component I could use to feed these 4 SDR at same time with the minimum loss. Since the SDR are only receiving, I have the feeling that isolation is not a key criteria.

Can you help me on finding what component to use to connect this antenna to the 4 SDRs ?
Thank you!

Comment: *...4 SDR at same time with the minimum loss.* Oh, you want minimum loss? Then why use one broadband antenna and splitters etc.? My guess is that that would introduce severe losses. I would give each SDR its own antenna optimized for the frequency band it is receiving and enjoy higher sensitivity.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie : that's what I am used to, but here there are physical constraints on the antenna

Comment: well, your passive diplexer is the right tool: just as you can use it to combine, you can use it to select

Comment: @MarcusMüller : To find a diplexer is fine, but a triplexer with these frequencies, I didn't manage. Would you have some models in mind? Do anybody know if that's complex to design oneself (I read contradictory posts on the internet about this) ?